# How to remove array elements when array is nested in multiple levels of embedded docs?

Tags: mongodb

Given the following MongoDB example collection ("schools"), how do you remove student "111" from all clubs?

```
[
  {
    "name": "P.S. 321",
    "structure": {
      "principal": "Fibber McGee",
      "vicePrincipal": "Molly McGee",
      "clubs": [
        {
          "name": "Chess",
          "students": [
            ObjectId("111"),
            ObjectId("222"),
            ObjectId("333")
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Cricket",
          "students": [
            ObjectId("111"),
            ObjectId("444")
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm hoping there's some way other than using cursors to loop over every school, then every club, then every student ID in the club...

Comment: Is this snippet a part of a bigger document? If yes, show the full structure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No, this is supposed to be one doc (i.e., the collection is the surrounding array). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't have a great support for arrays within arrays (within arrays ...). The simplest solution I see is to read the whole document into your app, modify it there and then save. This way, of course, the operation is not atomic, but for your app it might be ok.